# How to copy file to docker container running Lambda with AWS Toolkit in intelliJ

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, aws-toolkit

I am using AWS Toolkit in IntelliJ to run and test AWS Lambdas.  AWS Toolkit allows you to deploy a lambda and run it on an AWS system. Or you can run it locally in a Docker container.
Is there a way I can tell it to copy a local file into the Docker container?  I know how to do this normally with a Dockerfile, but in this case, the Dockerfile is hidden somewhere in the background.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using image based lambdas and specifying the location for the Dockerfile. You can use the AWS Toolkit to create image based lambdas (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/key-tasks.html#key-tasks-lambda-create)